# How can I know the cost associate to a source and the sink united by the same link in order to substrate the values?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

My net logo program has X sources and Y sinks. Sinks are united to sources (more than one sink can be united to more than one source, and even various sources or sinks united by each other).

Each sink and source is associate with a cost. I need to subtract link by link (abs value) the cost of the source and the sink united by that link. Or cost of source - cost of source, etc...

**For example 1: 
Link A-B** ; *links A to B (no mater if its source o sink)*

**abs (Nodalprice(A)-NodalPrice(B))**

**and this for each link**

Many thanks!